# SIM7000E Waveshare can't do anything

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, communication

Can someone help me? I'm using a sim7000e from Waveshare. One week ago it was working normally, but now it doesn't work at all; it even can't read the RX-TX communication.

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> //koneksi ke modem
    
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM7000
#define TINY_GSM_DEBUG SerialMon
#define BAUD 9600
#define SerialMon Serial

const byte rxpin = 2;
const byte txpin = 3;
    
SoftwareSerial SerialAT(rxpin, txpin); // RX, TX
```

That's  my code for connecting to the Arduino. I believe it from my Arduino, but I don't know if something wrong from Arduino.

My 5V (sim7000E) to 5V (arduino mega2560), GND to GND.

Because I'm using Putty on USB for reading my AT-cmd it doesn't and has some trouble.

Comment: Your rxpin on Arduino Mega2560 connect to which pin on SIM7000E?

Comment: Rx2=TX sim
Tx3=RX sim

Answer (score 2):

I'm having similar issues, although it could well be my fault!

I can't see any coding sending AT commands, or waiting for responses in your example.

Try running your TX pin to your RX pin on your Arduino (take the SIM7000e out of the equation completely).  If your code works, then the issue is elsewhere.

I've tried connecting via USB and that seems through a terminal.  I was able to connect to a mobile network using the AT command

AT+CSTT="cmnet"

Comment: Just to add further context, the Raspberry PI header pins use a lower TTL voltage.   Connecting to the other headers at the end of the board will give you compatible UART levels.   
Why your board has stopped working suddenly is a bit of a mystery, without proper context of pinouts,connectivity, power, etc.